Inertiajs onFinish not working in redux toolkit reducer
When I logout in the popup appears for confirmation when I click on it and out of the session it is fine the problem is when I register or sign in again the (isLogouting and isOpeLogoutDialogue) do not change to false. i provide all of the configure code about redux toolkit
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import GlobalReducer from "./GlobalReducer";
import GlobalStates from "./GlobalStates";

const GlobalSlice = createSlice({
    name: "global",
    initialState: GlobalStates,
    reducers: GlobalReducer,
});

export default GlobalSlice.reducer;
export const {
    handleOpenLogoutDialogue,
    handleCloseLogoutDialogue,
    handleLoggedOut,
} = GlobalSlice.actions;

const GlobalStates = {
    isOpeLogoutDialogue: false,
    isLogOuting: false,
};

export default GlobalStates;

      
  import { router } from "@inertiajs/react";
    
    const GlobalReducer = {
        handleLoggedOut(state, action, dispatch) {
            state.isLogOuting = true;
            router.post(route("logout"), {
                onFinish: () => {
                    state.isLogOuting = false;
                    state.isOpeLogoutDialogue = false;
                },
            });
        },
        handleOpenLogoutDialogue(state, action) {
            state.isOpeLogoutDialogue = true;
        },
        handleCloseLogoutDialogue(state, action) {
            state.isOpeLogoutDialogue = false;
        },
    };
    
    export default GlobalReducer;
    import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import AuthReducer from "./Slices/Auth/AuthSlice";
import GlobalReducer from "./Slices/Global/GlobalSlice";

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        auth: AuthReducer,
        global: GlobalReducer,
    }
});

export default store;


Reducers are pure functions, they can't call router.post and try to apply any asynchronous logic. This also doesn't look like Redux-Toolkit code, do you have some normal state slice these states/reducers belong to? In any case, your onFinish should dispatch actions to the store to effect any state changes.

Thanks for the information. about pure function, but this is redux code it does not look like redux code because I handle each file separately Like states/Slices and action reducers all are separate files and I bind all of these in my global slice method.

Yeah, that's kind of what I mean by it not looking like RTK code where it's all defined together and RTK generates the actions/etc for you. This also doesn't even look like regular Redux code. Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with here?

Ok I Am Editing the code.

@DrewReese i edit the code please review.

Reducers are pure functions, they can't call router.post and try to apply any asynchronous logic. The onFinish should dispatch actions to the store to effect any state changes.
I suggest refactoring this logic into an asynchronous action that can (a) apply asynchronous logic and (b) dispatch actions back to the store via the generated pending/fulfilled/rejected actions for you to handle in extra reducers.
Basic Example:
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { router } from "@inertiajs/react";
import GlobalStates from "./GlobalStates";

export const handleLoggedOut = createAsyncThunk(
  "global/handleLoggedOut",
  () => {
    return new Promise((resolve => {
      router.post(route("logout"), {
        onFinish: resolve,
      });
    }))
  }
);

const GlobalSlice = createSlice({
  name: "global",
  initialState: GlobalStates,
  reducers: {
    handleOpenLogoutDialogue(state) {
      state.isOpeLogoutDialogue = true;
    },
    handleCloseLogoutDialogue(state) {
      state.isOpeLogoutDialogue = false;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(handleLoggedOut.pending, () => {
        state.isLogOuting = true;
      })
      .addCase(handleLoggedOut.fulfilled, () => {
        state.isLogOuting = false;
        state.isOpeLogoutDialogue = false;
      })
      .addCase(handleLoggedOut.rejected, () => {
        state.isLogOuting = false;
        state.isOpeLogoutDialogue = false;
      });
  },
});

export const {
  handleOpenLogoutDialogue,
  handleCloseLogoutDialogue,
} = GlobalSlice.actions;

export default GlobalSlice.reducer;

